# get refresh token from authresult when using firebase to login on microsoft - Android

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, token, refresh, microsoft-graph-api

For a school project i am trying to make an app where people can log in using their microsoft account.

I am using firebase to handle authentication in my app. I managed to get an access token which allows me to use get calls to stuff like outlook.

Now i want to get a refresh token since i read those can last up to 90 days. I have no clue how to identify those or where in the AuthResult to find it. if someone requires certain code snippets please let me know i have no clue anymore.

Comment: Firebase Auth does not currently store or return refresh tokens (they only focus on the authentication part). Feel free to file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/).